# How to fix the windows security problem on GUI interaction through my service?

Tags: service, windows-10, javafx-8, interactive

Here I have build my application using javafx(GUI interaction).In linux and mac os using .sh it works fine.In windows also it works fine with .bat . But When it comes to java wrapper service the GUI window doesn't show up.

I have tried with setting these two property.
wrapper.ntservice.hide_console=true
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=true

The message window showed up was "a program running on this computer is trying to display a message " .When I click "view the message" It takes me to console on session 0 where I can't do anything.

`wrapper.ntservice.hide_console=true`
`wrapper.ntservice.interactive=true`

Here I expect to show the GUI through windows service.Please help with it

Comment: Why do you want to let a Windows Service show something on the desktop? That's not what they're supposed to do, they are background applications.

Comment: I have created my own service to launch a browser with specified url and log into that for further configuration and allow that to contact my server.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Then can u Suggest any other way to solve it?

Comment: @CodeCaster , Thanks for your help.After your comment thought that, is that possible and found the [Microsofts Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services)

Answer (score 0):

Finally ,I have found out that there is no way to run the GUI Application as the Windows Service . If anyone want run theirs as the service seperate the GUI code and Make them Communicate it.orelse don't use service as your choice.

-Thanks StackOverFlow,